@given not recognized even if behave imported
Am a first time user of python and behave stuff. I believe that, it's supposed to run without any issues as long as installed and imported. am on the same directory. The implementation is in vs code and @given is not recognized though behave imported as shown below.
behave --version
behave 1.2.6
from behave import *
@given('texts')
def step_imp():
pip3 rather than pip.

Since the import command does not rise a error. behave is importable.
Then only guess is that you have a behave directory in your current directory. So python tries to import from that folder instead of importing from the installed module.
A result of the command from "Note 2" (below) can help to understand the problem better.
Note 1: could you please use the following format for your code snippet. (Using triple backtick)
from behave import *

@given('texts')
def step_imp():
    ...

Note 2:
While behave doc suggests from behave import * it is not a best practice. As an example, with the following import you can see a better error message. (Also such imports helps to know from which module an entity is imported
from behave import given


Thank you for the input. It's not the import, it turned out that the issue was from the module my team should have updated.

@Tes Thank you for the info. Could you please consider add the solution you found and the code formatting into the question
